# Help with wine installation

Tags: wine, games

I installed wine and then realized i should have installed winehq. I used the code:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-devel
```

I got this response:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblcms2-2 : Breaks: liblcms2-2:i386 (!= 2.5-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
 liblcms2-2:i386 : Breaks: liblcms2-2 (!= 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1) but 2.5-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
 wine1.6-amd64 : Conflicts: wine-amd64
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Conflicts: wine-i386
 winehq-devel : Depends: wine-devel
                Conflicts: wine
                Conflicts: wine:i386
                Conflicts: wine-amd64
                Conflicts: wine-amd64:i386
                Conflicts: wine-i386
                Conflicts: wine-i386:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

so then i type in the command it tells me to and i get this:

```
bob@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for bob: 
root@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm3.4 libopenvg1-mesa libwayland-egl1-mesa
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblcms2-2
Suggested packages:
  liblcms2-utils
The following packages will be upgraded:
  liblcms2-2
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 110 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/134 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  liblcms2-2
Install these packages without verification? [y/N] y
E: Invalid archive signature
E: Internal error, could not locate member control.tar.{gzbz2xzlzma}
E: Prior errors apply to /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
debconf: apt-extracttemplates failed: No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: `/var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb' is not a debian format archive
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess dpkg-deb --control returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/liblcms2-2_2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help me because these are the same errors I keep getting when trying to install anything now.

Edit: I was trying to install a game. Here's what I ended up with:

```
root@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~# sudo apt-get install smc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblcms2-2 : Breaks: liblcms2-2:i386 (!= 2.5-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
 liblcms2-2:i386 : Breaks: liblcms2-2 (!= 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1) but 2.5-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
 smc : Depends: libboost-filesystem1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libboost-thread1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libcegui-mk2-0.7.6 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-mixer1.2 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-ttf2.0-0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: smc-data (= 1.9+git20121121-1ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Edit 2:

```
bob@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ sudo apt-get install synaptic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblcms2-2 : Breaks: liblcms2-2:i386 (!= 2.5-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
 liblcms2-2:i386 : Breaks: liblcms2-2 (!= 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1) but 2.5-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
 synaptic : Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: rarian-compat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
bob@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege
bob@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~$ sudo -s
root@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: error processing package liblcms2-2:i386 (--configure):
 package liblcms2-2:i386 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 cannot be configured because liblcms2-2:amd64 is at a different version (2.5-0ubuntu4.1)
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-i386:
 wine1.6-i386 depends on liblcms2-2 (>= 2.2+git20110628); however:
  Package liblcms2-2:i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-i386 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6:
 wine1.6 depends on wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4); however:
  Package wine1.6-i386 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine:
 wine depends on wine1.6 | wine1.8; however:
  Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.
  Package wine1.8 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package wine (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of wine1.6-amd64:
 wine1.6-amd64 depends on wine1.6:any (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4); however:
   Package wine1.6 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package wine1.6-amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  liblcms2-2:i386
  wine1.6-i386
  wine1.6
  wine
  wine1.6-amd64
```

Edit: this is what i got at the end. there is entirely too much to put here but i did the

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
```

there was a whole bunch of stuff in between but ended like this:

```
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Depends: wine1.6:any:i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4)
                 Recommends: wine-mono0.0.8:i386
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: >root@bob-HP-Stream-Notebook-PC-11:~# sudo apt-get --purge remove wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liblcms2-2 : Breaks: liblcms2-2:i386 (!= 2.5-0ubuntu4.1) but 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1 is to be installed
 liblcms2-2:i386 : Breaks: liblcms2-2 (!= 2.6-3ubuntu1~trusty1) but 2.5-0ubuntu4.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: You installed winehq? That's the site of wine. devel means development version. So, you installed the development version of wine. Which rarely works because it's ... under development. Don't mess with devel unless you are a developer and you know your stuff well. Doing `--install -recommends`won't guarantee your success.

Comment: I tried installing a game and get the error i posted in the comments

Comment: @AzariusJenkins Please don’t post multi-line code in comments because it’ll break formatting. Edit the question instead.

Comment: ok i will do that now

Comment: @Azarius Jenkins: winehq is a very good site, having a very large database of games. First check out other users' opinions and see IF your game runs fine in wine. It would be a lot easier if you'd install a stable (older) version of wine and PlayOnLinux (POL) too. `Unmet dependencies` means wine needs some packages that aren't available for the Ubuntu version you're currently running. Those packages will become available when the wine version you're using right now will 'graduate' to 'unstable' or 'stable' status.

Comment: the version i have currently is 1.6

Comment: Did you completely uninstalled the other wine version first? Anyways, just go to Synaptic and uninstall ALL wine-related packages from ALL versions of it. Then , go to (Gnome) Software and install Wine from there. That version should always work.

Comment: @ipselute he doesn't have synaptic installed and since he has broken packages neither will synaptic get installed now

Comment: @rancho: And doing a force-install (without meting dependencies) will repair broken packages how?

Comment: @ipselute extremely bd idea to do it this way, may corrupt the entire system leaving the only option of reinstall

Comment: I think I may have fixed it by using 

    sudo apt-get --reinstall install liblcms2-2

I'll post back when im finished trying to install this game but as of right now everything seems to be working again. its not coming up with errors anymore and it said it installed wine and the liblcms2-2. Hopefully this fixes it and seriously, THANK YOU GUS for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to conflict between 32 bit and 64 bit packages

Press

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Terminal opens

Type

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge wine*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo -f install
sudo autoremove
sudo autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install winehq
apt -f install
```

Comment: i edited the post to include what you said to do...

Comment: Try my terminal commands excluding the last line first

Comment: i keep getting the same stuff as ive posted already

Comment: Corrected my answer Try it

Comment: @AzariusJenkins Please provide feedback

Comment: it is 3805 characters too long to post... its the same thing over and over again

Comment: Please post it at http://pastebin.com/ and paste the link in comment

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iiFatvJj

Comment: Try   rm -rf  wine1.8-i386,  give me the output

Comment: didnt do anything but put me down a line

Comment: I am sorry I am an idiot, silly mistake

Comment: do,  sudo apt-get remove -f wine1.8-i386

Comment: If successful do sudo apt-get remove -f wine*

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8vq7s39Q

Comment: either way try apt-get remove -f wine* as last rescue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41604/discussion-between-azarius-jenkins-and-rancho).